# Python logging CloudWatch location?

Tags: python, logging, aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a Lambda function, which I've declared with CDK. Additionally, I've declared cloud watch logs and passed the resource to the Lambda function as an environment variable "LOGS_DESTINATION".

The location can be retrieved by `os.environ['LOGS_DESTINATION']` by Python Lambda.

In Python, using the logging module, how I can configure/direct logging.info statements to cloudwatch logs using the above location (which is a string)?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to take care of anything, essentially. Especially, you do not need to provide or retrieve the path to the logs.

From the documentation the important parts are the following:

1. > AWS Lambda automatically monitors Lambda functions [...] As long as your function's execution role has the necessary permissions, Lambda captures logs for all requests handled by your function and sends them to Amazon CloudWatch Logs.
2. > You can insert logging statements into your code to help you validate that your code is working as expected. Lambda automatically integrates with CloudWatch Logs and sends all logs from your code to a CloudWatch logs group associated with a Lambda function.
3. > By default, Lambda sends logs to a log group named /aws/lambda/<function name>. If you want your function to send logs to another group, you can configure this using the Lambda console, the AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI) or the Lambda AP

Quoted from [the official documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/monitoring-cloudwatchlogs.html).
From the console you can either search cloudwatch log groups directly or navigate to your lambda and the "Monitor" section. There, you will find a link "View CloudWatch logs" that takes you where you want to go.

Answer (score 0):

```
logging.getLogger().setLevel('INFO')
```

Comment: A little bit of explanation how this addresses OP's issue might help.